# Strip words between first two forwardslashes

Tags: java, regex

I have a string

```
String origStr = "/unwanted/wanted1/wanted2/and_so_on"
```

i want to make this as

```
String finalStr = "wanted1/wanted2/and_so_on"
```

I thought of doing that using regEx in Java. But struck on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
origStr.replaceFirst("/[^/]+/", "");
```

should work

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this -

```
    String str = "/unwanted/wanted1/wanted2/and_so_on";
    String temp = str.substring(str.indexOf("/", 1)+1);
    System.out.println(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using regEx.You can use `split("/")` method to make it into String array.And cutting down the first element.

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] arr= origSTr.split("/");
```

Use this arr as you wish.

Comment: there's also a `split (String regex, int limit)` method, `limit` can be set to `3`, and the third element of the result array is the finalString; `String finalStr = origStr.split("/",3) [2];`